# AMD A10-6700 Support?

Tags: boot, system-installation, asus, amd-processor

I cannot get Ubuntu installed on my new ASUS system. How do I find a list of AMD A10-6700 and Asus support issues? Specifically installation problems.

Thanks

Comment: I have an Asus main-board with the same CPU, and Ubuntu runs fine on it.  Is it giving you any errors?

Comment: It fails the install with a kernel panic. I've tried a variety Ubuntu levels in both 32 and 64 bit.  It fails both the install and try with out installing options.

Comment: Are booting UEFI or not?

Comment: The BIOS is ASUS UEFI ver 0403 date 12-24-2013 - so I guess that means yes. I have a screen shot of the text console that appears when it fails but I can't post it - I can send it via email or text.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem
I have bought an Asus X552E, AMD A4 with Radeon HD 8670M gpu. I want to install ubuntu 14.04 on it but I have a strange problem. when I start installing, the LCD of laptop encounters with graphical problems. it shows the screen in pixel pixel format as if the gpu is out of order! but when I reboot the laptop and use Win 8.1, there is no graphical problem in the screen!

I have checked the gpu in support of Asus in my country, they told me this chip is fine and maybe the ubuntu is havibg conflict on AMD or Radeon gpu!

I dont know what to do!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/185696) on a similar question.
This might resolve the issue.