# 60% CPU Usage just moving my mouse around | Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, mouse, amd-graphics, cpu

So last night I decided to return to Linux after reviewing the way Microsoft manufactures consent for surveillance type behaviour on their Windows operating system.

I'm having a problem with high CPU usage just moving around my mouse in Firefox I get 30% CPU usage and 30% web content usage which seems a tad high for my CPU which is actually an AMD A10-4655m APU with Radeon HD graphics × 4. This problem also occurs just moving my mouse over the dock icons to the left which causes the CPU usage to spike to 30% also for gnome-shell.

The machine feels sluggish, I have looked in the additional drivers area but there are no additional drivers available and I am kind of stuck from where to go from here so I am relying on your kind responses.

There is actually a post from 2012 [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166538/problems-with-ubuntu-and-amd-a10-4655m-apu) which tells you how to install proprietary drivers but on installation I did check the mark to install 3rd party drivers at the point of installation.

Is there any way to fix this problem and give me a bit of speed so I can stick with Ubuntu. Thank you for taking the time to help me out in advance.

Comment: You can use `htop` or for this case maybe better [`glances`](https://nicolargo.github.com/glances/) to get exactly which processes are taking your CPU time. Would be nice to have the output of `inxi -SMIG -! 31`.

Comment: You're using radeon drivers? I have an A8 and use "oibaf" amdgpu drivers, `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu ` should get you the amdgpu drivers but if there's no improvement you might have to blacklist radeon.

Comment: This could have been caused by this (fixed) gnome-shell bug https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/issues/283